# Connect 2 4K monitors to a M1 Pro laptop via Thunderbolt 4 dock?

Tags: macbook-pro, mac, display, thunderbolt, apple-silicon

Is it possible to connect two external 4K60 monitors to a M1 Pro macbook using a single Thunderbolt 4 port, more specifically using a dock?

I have researched this and am getting conflicting answers. The [official docs](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202351) aren't helpful, as they don't specify this. I found [this related question](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/253341707) on Apple forums, and some answers there say it's possible.

But then I asked the specific question there myself, and [got an opposite answer](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/253444895?answerId=256445109022).

I called Apple, and the rep also said that this is not possible even with the M1 Max (only one monitor per port), but I am not 100% confident in their knowledge.

People [here](https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/m1-pro-max-one-cable-solution.2321817/page-2) are sharing their personal experiences and confirming that it does work with specific setups.

Answer (score 2):

Yes this is possible.
I'm doing this with a Thunderbolt 3 dock. Specifically [HP G2 Thunderbolt Dock G2](https://www.hp.com/us-en/shop/pdp/hp-thunderbolt-dock-120w-g2). The crux is to connect one display to the DisplayPort and the other to a Thunderbolt port (provided your dock has one). Based on the [specs listed](https://www.apple.com/macbook-pro-14-and-16/specs/) on Apple’s website your MacBook is capable of running 2x 6K@60. The dock merely acts as Thunderbolt pass through. So you should be good.

This is inline with the statement in Apple's support article [About the Thunderbolt ports on Mac](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/about-the-thunderbolt-ports-mh35952/mac):

> Depending on your Mac, you may be able to connect multiple Thunderbolt devices to each other, then connect the chain of devices to the Thunderbolt port on your Mac. See Use one or more external displays with your Mac.

Dell has [instructions](https://www.dell.com/support/kbdoc/nl-nl/000124312/dell-thunderbolt-dock-wd19tb-and-apple-usb-c-hosts?lang=en#Dual_Monitor) for this specific setup (2x 4K@60Hz) with their WD19TB Dock:

[image: Dell WD19TB Dock connections]
Dell also instructs to connect one display to the Thunderbolt port on the dock and the other to Displayport or HDMI.

Wirecutter mentions a similar setup in their [review of Thunderbolt docks](https://www.nytimes.com/wirecutter/reviews/best-thunderbolt-dock/):

> The second Thunderbolt port allows you to pass through data from Thunderbolt accessories. You can hook up two 4K monitors at 60 Hz, too,

OWC, known for its Mac accessories, also has a [dock](https://www.owcdigital.com/products/thunderbolt-3-dock-14-port) that can do this. On the page about this dock, they refer to an [infographic](https://www.owcdigital.com/assets/dealer/files/thunderbolt-daisy-chain-inforgraphic.pdf) on Thunderbolt.

My specs below for reference.

[image]

```
Apple M1 Pro:

  Chipset Model:    Apple M1 Pro
  Type: GPU
  Bus:  Built-In
  Total Number of Cores:    14
  Vendor:   Apple (0x106b)
  Metal Family: Supported, Metal GPUFamily Apple 7
  Displays:
DELL U2518D:
  Resolution:   2560 x 1440 (QHD/WQHD - Wide Quad High Definition)
  UI Looks like:    2560 x 1440 @ 60.00Hz
  Main Display: Yes
  Mirror:   Off
  Online:   Yes
  Rotation: Supported
  Automatically Adjust Brightness:  Yes
Color LCD:
  Display Type: Built-in Liquid Retina XDR Display
  Resolution:   3024 x 1964 Retina
  Mirror:   Off
  Online:   Yes
  Automatically Adjust Brightness:  No
  Connection Type:  Internal
DELL P2417H:
  Resolution:   1920 x 1080 (1080p FHD - Full High Definition)
  UI Looks like:    1920 x 1080 @ 60.00Hz
  Mirror:   Off
  Online:   Yes
  Rotation: Supported
  Automatically Adjust Brightness:  Yes
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132382/discussion-on-answer-by-volsk-connect-2-4k-monitors-to-a-m1-pro-laptop-via-thund).

Comment: Thank you! Can confirm this works on an M1 Pro 2021 running 12.6.3. The key was connecting the second monitor to the thunderbolt port on the right, rather than the USB-C/DisplayPort port on the left. A subtle difference that did not matter on my older Intel Mac, but it appears absolutely required for Apple silicon.

Comment: Confirm this works on an Intel MBP running 14.1 and a HP TB dock G4.  

Took a bit of fiddling to realize I was using the wrong USB C port (I was using the one shared with the DP port on the left).

Once I identified that, it works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to connect two external 4K60 monitors to a M1 Pro macbook using a single Thunderbolt 4 port, more specifically using a dock?

No, it's not possible.  There are exceptions that I'll get into but generally no, that is not possible.  This has been a long time complaint of Apple computers and it does not appear Apple is going to change this.

The main issue is Apple does not support MST, multi-stream transport, over DisplayPort.  This means one port supports only one display.

Apple states on their website that computers with M1 and Thunderbolt 4 support only one display per port. It's in their support page on connecting displays: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202351
And on identifying ports: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201736

The exceptions to this are displays controlled by a separate GPU.  Someone could plug in a dock with a DisplayPort output and USB, and then use a USB GPU like those made by DisplayLink to drive the second display.  Some docks have DisplayLink GPUs built-in to them for multiple displays.  Another means to get an external GPU is with a box that is clearly labeled an external GPU.  These are docks with a primary function of adding additional graphics processing, though this processing is available to be used on an internal display as well as external displays.  These eGPU docks will tend to have other ports like USB and Ethernet but some do not as their function is to be a GPU, not a general purpose dock, and so may lack such ports as they take valuable bandwidth.

If connecting two displays by one Thunderbolt cable is important to you then you are going to have to pay for it.  There is no cheap resolution to this.  Windows will support two displays on a single Thunderbolt port but you pay for it in a different way, lower video performance.  Two 4K@60 displays on one Thunderbolt port is asking a lot, if it works at all then it's likely by "cheating" with compressed video.  Maybe the math works out and no cheating required but it's getting real close to the limits of the cables.

DisplayLink and eGPU get by with less bandwidth on the cable to the computer because the video is still a stream of descriptive bits at that point.  After processing into the full uncompressed video frame there's more data.  After processing there is more bandwidth consumed on the cable to the display, one 4K@60Hz consumes more data than one DisplayPort channel can hold.  Supporting two 4K displays means using all 4 "superspeed" channels in the USB-C cable for video, leaving no channels for Thunderbolt or USB 3.x, or multiplexing the DisplayPort video into the same "superspeed" channels, which is a feature not all displays and docks support.  I speculate but it's likely safe to assume Apple didn't want to confuse users with the long list of technical requirements on what is needed to get two displays on one Thunderbolt port to work and simply says it is not supported.  They "enforce" this limitation by not including MST support in their OS and drivers, without MST there's no multiplexing two DisplayPort streams on one cable.

Comment: So to clarify - is this answer wrong or do those people who are reporting it working all have docks with DisplayLink and that's why it's working?

Comment: >`Apple states on their website that computers with M1 and Thunderbolt 4 support only one display per port` I'm asking about M1 Pro/Max, though, and they don't say anything like that regarding them.

Comment: @gshpychka " I'm asking about M1 Pro/Max, though, and they don't say anything like that regarding them. "  That's not how I read it.  I'll phrase my claim differently then, as Apple makes no mention of supporting more than one display per port the assumption is that this is not supported.  If Apple supported two 4K displays on a single Thunderbolt 4 port then they'd have a document stating how to make it work.  If there is a non-Apple product that offers two 4K displays on one port then you'd have to look for how to make this work from the people that make that product, not from Apple.

Comment: Addendum to emphasize an earlier point...  The way to know if a dock is using DisplayLink to drive multiple displays is to do a little research on the dock.  A dock that is using DisplayLink will almost certainly have the DisplayLink trademark on it.  A dock using DisplayLink will need drivers to make it work, will have the device appear in System Information, will have DisplayLink mentioned in the technical specifications, and an app to configure the GPU should appear somewhere on the computer's boot drive.  It should not be difficult to discover but also it may not be obvious from a glance.

Comment: `That's not how I read it` that's definitely what they meant, though - the original M1 only supports 1 external monitor, M1 Pro supports 2, M1 Max supports 4. They don't say anything about not supporting them on a single port, that's still up for interpretation. Another important thing that contradicts your answer is that Intel-based Macs do support multiple 4K screens on one port. And also the fact that the Apple rep told me that the M1 Pro/Max do as well, just not 4K.

Comment: @gshpychka Please define "authoritative source" so that I may answer your question with an authoritative source as you requested in your bounty.  If you are seeing sources that say two 4K displays on one Thunderbolt 4 port is possible then perhaps you need to go to that source for clarification.  Apple makes no mention of supporting more than one display on Thunderbolt 4 ports, and Apple should be an authority on this.  Absence of evidence is not evidence of absence but so far that's all I can offer.

Comment: the M1 Max supports six displays, and it has 4 ports. It definitely supports multiple external displays on one port. "Authoritative source" would be something that cites the actual capabilities of the chip and explains clearly how to achieve 2 4K displays on one port without simply trial and error. Either Apple or an established internet outlet.

Comment: The M1 Max supports displays on 1 HDMI, 3 Thunderbolt, 1 internal, and 1 WiFi (iPad Sidecar), no support for 2 displays on 1 port required to get 6 displays.

Comment: 6 external displays. It definitely supports multiple displays on one port.

Comment: @gshpychka " 6 external displays. "  Says who?  Would this source not also say how it's done?  Perhaps that was done with DisplayLink but it seems that is not an answer you will accept.

Answer (score 0):

This one will do it with one cable. Note that it does not use (or need) Thunderbolt 4 to do so:

[VT4510 Dual Display 4K USB 3.0 & USB-C Docking Station with 100W Power Delivery](https://www.visiontek.com/products/vt4510-dual-display-4k-usb-3-0-usb-c-docking-station-with-100w-power-delivery?variant=41984092930260)

Comment: True. But it does use DisplayLink and it's not Thunderbolt but USB-C.

Comment: @Volsk  I know I may be overly pedantic but USB-C is not distinct from Thunderbolt (TB).  USB-C is the physical connector, a connector that can carry either TB or USB 3.x protocols at the same time.  USB4 allows for "superspeed" USB and TB on USB-C at the same time.  TB can use USB-C or mini-DisplayPort for the physical connection.  USB 3.x can use USB-C or USB-A on the host port.  USB4 is a superset of both TB and USB 3.x on a USB-C port.  The dock given in the answer is not TB and so does not technically answer the question but perhaps meets the intended goals.

Answer (score 0):

M1 Mac can have only one native external display connected. However, it had been improved with M1 Pro Mac and M1 Max Mac systems(released after 10/2021.
The new M1 Pro or M1 Max Mac systems can support up to 6 external monitors at the same time totally.

I had tested and proofed this new video supported capacity with the new M1 Pro/ M1 Max accordingly.

I added a Thunderbolt 4 HUB or Thunderbolt 4 dock to any of built-in Thunderbolt 4 ports on the Mac systems and the HUB/docks have up to 3 Thunderbolt ports or video ports on it.

Comment: This does not answer the question of whether they support 2 4K displays on one port.